# buttons inside the drawerLayout dont work

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I have problem with drawerLayout. in drawerLayout, i have two Linearlayouts. one is the main menu that shows directly, the otherone is active with drawer slide. when i slide the drawer menü i cant click the buttons. but when i remove the second linearLayout then the buttons in the drawer work. how can i solve it?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=""
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@color/list_back"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="setContentView"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ana Sayfa"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAnaSayfa"
            android:onClick="setContentView"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kalori Tablosu"
            android:id="@+id/buttonKalori"
            android:onClick="setContentView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contextClickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Glisemik İndeks Tablosu"
            android:id="@+id/buttonGITablosu"
            android:onClick="setContentView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contextClickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vücut Kütle İndeksi"
            android:id="@+id/buttonVucutKutle"
            android:onClick="setContentView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contextClickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonKaloriListesi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kalori_listesi_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonGITablosu"
        android:src="@drawable/gi_tablosu_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonKaloriListesi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi"
        android:src="@drawable/bugun_kac_kalori_aldin_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks"
        android:src="@drawable/vucut_kutle_indeksi_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/buttontest1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my .java ;

```
package com.azelirbrevo.glisemikindeks


public class "" extends AppCompatActivity {


//DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
//ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

//CharSequence actionBarTitle, appTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstaftersplash);

    ImageButton ImageButtonKaloriListesi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonKaloriListesi);

    ImageButton imageButtonGITablosu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGITablosu);

    ImageButton imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks);

    ImageButton imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi);

    ImageButtonKaloriListesi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, KaloriListesi.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    imageButtonGITablosu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, GITablosu.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, VucutKutleIndexHesaplama.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, bugunKacKaloriAldim.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    //drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    //actionBarTitle = appTitle = getSupportActionBar().getTitle();


    Button buttonAnasayfa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnaSayfa);
    Button buttonKalori = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonKalori);
    Button buttonGı = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGITablosu);
    Button buttonVucutKutle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVucutKutle);
    Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontest1);

    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, TEST.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    buttonAnasayfa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tiklandi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, GITablosu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    buttonKalori.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tiklandi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, GITablosu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    buttonGı.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tiklandi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, GITablosu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    buttonVucutKutle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tiklandi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(firstAfterSplash.this, GITablosu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

[this is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcxtA.jpg)

Comment: not proper explanation, please add more info like Activity Class or onClick event

Comment: \ Drawer Layout place views in Z order so whichever is on top (in code whichever is last) get focused So check what is getting clicked

Comment: thank you Gaurav, it helped. I just get the slider menu codes under the others in xml and worked.

Comment: please paste updated code in answer so it will be helpful for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml file, my drawer menu items (LinearLayout and Buttons) were over my main LinearLayout. I just cut-paste it under the main LinearLayout and it helped.
here is the updated xml file of my project, hope will help someone.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=""
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonKaloriListesi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kalori_listesi_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonGITablosu"
        android:src="@drawable/gi_tablosu_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonKaloriListesi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi"
        android:src="@drawable/bugun_kac_kalori_aldin_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonVucutKutleIndeks"
        android:src="@drawable/vucut_kutle_indeksi_button"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButtonBugunKaloriHesabi"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="setContentView"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#85c7f1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDrawerAnaSayfa"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDrawerKalori"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDrawerGI"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDrawerVucutKutle"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a application with Navigation drawer Activity here you can see custom layout inside drawer layout and inside layout you can set any type of widgets as button, TextView and any type what ever you want.